# Node.js promise request return

Tags: node.js, request, promise

I'm using the promis module to return my json data from the request module, but every time i run it, it gives me this.

```
Promise { _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }
```

I can't get it to work, any one know the problem? here is my code:

```
function parse(){
return new Promise(function(json){
    request('https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_account_balance/?api_key='+api+'&code='+code, function (error, response, body) {
        json(JSON.parse(body).data.available_balance);
    });
});
}

console.log(parse());
```

Comment: Promises return a promise, a contract that it will resolve (.then) or reject (.catch) with some data at a later point. I suggest reading up on them. Your logging the returned promise. Your request hasn't returned at that point.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A promise is an object that serves as a placeholder for a future value.  Your `parse()` function returns that promise object.  You get the future value in that promise by attaching a `.then()` handler to the promise like this:

```
function parse(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request('https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_account_balance/?api_key='+api+'&code='+code, function (error, response, body) {
            // in addition to parsing the value, deal with possible errors
            if (err) return reject(err);
            try {
                // JSON.parse() can throw an exception if not valid JSON
                resolve(JSON.parse(body).data.available_balance);
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
}

parse().then(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.err(err);
});
```

This is asynchronous code so the ONLY way you get the value out of the promise is via the `.then()` handler.

List of modifications:

1. Add `.then()` handler on returned promise object to get final result.
2. Add `.catch()` handler on returned promise object to handle errors.
3. Add error checking on `err` value in `request()` callback.
4. Add try/catch around `JSON.parse()` since it can throw if invalid JSON

Answer (score 8):

Use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise):

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function (response) {
        // resolved
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // rejected
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
const request = require('request')

/* --- */

/* 
    "Producing Code" (May take some time) 
 */
let myPromise = new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {

    request( 'https://example.com', function ( error, response, body ) {

        if ( error ) return reject( error )
        
        try {

            resolve( body )
            
        } catch ( error ) {
            
            reject( error )
            
        }
        
    } )
    
} )

/* --- */

/* 
    "Consuming Code" (Must wait for a fulfilled Promise) 
 */
myPromise.then(
    
    function( success ) { 
        
        /* code if successful */ 
        console.log( success )
        
    },
    
    function( error ) { 
        
        /* code if some error */ 
        console.error( error )
        
    }
    
)
```