# Variable is not reading value in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting output as `undefined` in the last line of code. Ideally it should print the value of `cost` variable which I have assigned in the last line of `call function` . `cost variable` is printing value correctly. what mistake I am making. or how can I access value of `cost` outside the `function`.

```
var request = require("request");
 var itemCost;

 function call() {

   request.get("http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar", (error, response, body) => {

            if (error) {
                return console.dir(error);
            }
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
            let obj = new Object(jsonData);

            obj.items.forEach(itemChild => {
                let cost = itemChild.itemcost;
                console.log(cost);
                itemCost = cost;  //Assigning value of cost to itemcost. is this correct way?
            })

        });
    }

    call();
    console.log(itemCost); //here I am getting undefined. I want value of cost here.
```

Comment: of course? `request.get` is asynchronous, so it gets called, gets scheduled for resolution at some later time, your code _immediately_ continues to `call()` and `console.log`, and by the time `itemCost` actually gets set, the rest of your code is done already: don't console.log a value until you have that value (e.g. put your console log alongside the same code that _sets_ itemCost)

Comment: Basically I have to access that value in some other function. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `request.get` is **asynchronous**, you have to log that `itemCost` inside your **callback** otherwise you need to chain your operation with **Promises**(here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412836/5656255)) or sth.

Its undefined because `console.log(itemCost);` doesn't actually wait for `request.get` to get finished so the `itemCost` is not calculated until you reach to that line.

> Basically I have to access that value in some other function. is there
>   any way to do that?

You can call the function inside your callback by just passing the `itemCost` variable. For example

```
request.get("http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar", (error, response, body) => {

    if (error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
    let obj = new Object(jsonData);

    obj.items.forEach(itemChild => {
       let cost = itemChild.itemcost;
       console.log(cost);
       itemCost = cost;  //Assigning value of cost to itemcost. is this correct way?
    })

    foo(itemCost); //call the method you need by passing the calculated variable

     });
    }
```