# My firebase function is returning null when doing nested api calls

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am creating an angular-based e-commerce app and this is the API call for checking the product shipment info. But this function is returning a null value when called.

Here is the code of my function:

```
exports.checkOrderShipment = functions.https.onCall(
  (req: any, context: any) => {
    if (!context.auth)
      return { status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in' };
    // console.log('checkOrderShipment', req);
    // console.log('checkOrderShipment CORS METHOD');
    let authOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external/auth/login',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: 'test',
        password: 'test',
      }),
    };
    var a = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      request(authOptions, function (error: any, authResponse: any, body: any) {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        try {
          resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
    return a.then(function (data: any) {
      // console.log('authApi', data, typeof data);
      // console.log(data);
      let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url:
          'https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external/courier/track/shipment/' +
          req.shipmentId,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + data.token,
        },
      };
      var shipmentData = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error: any, response: any) {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          // console.log('checkOrderShipment API RESPONSE', response);
          resolve({data: {
            res: response,
            req: req,
            body: response.body,
          },});
        });
      });
      shipmentData.then(function (data: any) {
        console.log('shipmentData', data);
        return data;
      });

    });
  }
);
```

Here is my calling method:

My services file :

```
checkShipmentDetail(shipmentId){
    return this.firebaseFunction.httpsCallable('checkOrderShipment')(shipmentId);
    // return this.http.post(environment.cloudFunctions.checkOrderShipment, {shipmentId:shipmentId});
  }
```

My component typescript page function:

```
this.paymentService
        .checkShipmentDetail(shipmentID)
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
          console.log('check',res)})
```

I am new to the `onCall` function and know nothing about how promises work in firebase functions. Now I knwo how to use on the Request method. Actually, I was using it previously but because of so many security problems and App Check I am moving to `onCall` method for `functions`.

Helpful link I found:

[Node.js promise request return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412512/node-js-promise-request-return)

And if possible also tell how to only allow authorized people to access the cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference):

> An `https.onCall` trigger for Cloud Functions is an HTTPS trigger with a specific format for the request and response.`

In there you could see the specifics about the format and request and response body.

Also I recommend you to check this other [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that shows you how to write and deploy and deploy a callable function.

On the other hand the way to manage the access to your functions is with the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).